# Creating Edgelist from DataFrame with column containing multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing some champions and their related traits, it looks like this:

| Index | Champion | Traits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alphelios | 'Nightbringer', 'Ranger' |
| 1 | Ashe | 'Draconic', 'Ranger' |
| 2 | Heimerdinger | 'Renewer', 'Draconic', 'Caretaker' |
| 3 | Lee Sin | 'Nightbringer', 'Skirmisher' |

Where the Traits are represented as: ['Nightbringer', 'Ranger'], ['Draconic', 'Ranger'], ect.

... and so forth.

I wish to create an edgelist with the champions and those champions that has the same trait, as is;

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

.. The list goes on. I'd also like the last DataFrame to contain a column with the weights, for example if two champions have the same two traits, or even tree, then it will have a weight of 2 (3). I think the dataframe should be extended so that each champion has several rows (containing each of their trait), but I can't seem to find a solution to the problem. Can anybody help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: Get your data in "tidy data format" and follow solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669575/edgelist-pandas-get-number-of-common-values-between-two-combos-in-a-column/69669823#69669823

Comment: tidy data: https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict with the indexes of all occurrences of a trait:

```
my_dict = {}

for i, j in enumerate(df['Traits']):
    for trait in j:
        if trait in my_dict:
            my_dict[trait].append(i)
        else:
            my_dict[trait] = [i]
print(my_dict)
```

The output:

```
{'Nightbringer': [0, 3], 'Ranger': [0, 1], 'Draconic': [1, 2], 'Renewer': [2], 'Caretaker': [2], 'Skirmisher': [3]}
```

This is a better approach because you don't get unnecessary repetition, e.g. `0 points to 3` and `3 points to 0`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but still not exactly what I'm looking for. The three last columns 'Renewer', 'Caretaker' and 'Skirmisher' should not be included in the edgelist. I'm thinking that it should do something like 'for each Trait - If equal to another Trait - (append?) the INDEX', so that I get a list of each relation (0,1 for example)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to count the number of other rows with matching traits.

Use a combination of `str.get_dummies` and numpy:

*NB. This assumes Traits are strings, if lists just get dummies from the list instead*

```
import numpy as np

a = df.Traits.str.get_dummies(sep=',').values
b = a.dot(a.T)
np.fill_diagonal(b, 0)

pd.DataFrame({'Source': df['Index'],
              'Target': b.sum(1)})
```

Output:

```
   Source  Target
0       0       2
1       1       1
2       2       0
3       3       1
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but still not exactly what I'm looking for. The three last columns 'Renewer', 'Caretaker' and 'Skirmisher' should not be included in the edgelist. I'm thinking that it should do something like 'for each Trait - If equal to another Trait - (append?) the INDEX', so that I get a list of each relation (0,1 for example)